# Performance difference between positional and keyword arguments in Python?

Tags: python, performance, arguments

There are many explanations of the difference between positional and keyword arguments for Python functions on StackOverflow and the difference in utility is clear to me. However, I was unable to find a clear answer (and perhaps explanation of) whether positional arguments are substantially faster that keyword arguments in some situations.

On the one hand, I can imagine they would be, as there has to be no work done to look up the arguments passed. But on the other hand, unless the arguments are passed as a `dict` spread into the `**kwargs`, or something like that, I imagine the compiler may just optimise this problem away and the bytecode might perform nearly identical for base cases.

So:

```py
from timeit import timeit


def fun1(a, b, c):
    pass  # or some operation that wouldn't get this function optimised out altogether


def fun2(a, /, b, c=3):
    pass  # or some operation that wouldn't get this function optimised out altogether


fun1(1, 2, 3)  # call 1
fun2(1, 2, 3)  # call 2
fun2(1, 2, c=3)  # call 3
fun2(1, b=2, c=3)  # call 4
d = {'c': 3}
fun2(1, 2, *d)  # call 5
```

My question is: which ones of these calls are slower than the others and why? And am I missing a key example that would focus on the worst performance hit here?

I would assume call 5 is clearly worst, as Python needs to assess at runtime what parameters have been passed. But it depends on optimisation whether calls 4 and 3 are dealt with more efficiently. And for call 1 to be faster than call 2, there would have to be little or no optimisation at all.

I appreciate that the answer may depend on the specific Python compiler / VM implementation, so I'm asking in particular about the default Python interpreter that most people will be using.

Of course one could just write a script to measure the difference, but I feel that's going to get muddied real quick by whatever the function does and perhaps some local circumstances, so I was hoping someone would read this question and actually know *why* there would be a difference once way or the other.

I *did* run a timer test and it confirmed my suspicions:

```py
print(timeit(lambda: fun1(1, 2, 3), number=int(1e8)))  # call 1
print(timeit(lambda: fun2(1, 2, 3), number=int(1e8)))  # call 2
print(timeit(lambda: fun2(1, 2, c=3), number=int(1e8)))  # call 3
print(timeit(lambda: fun2(1, b=2, c=3), number=int(1e8)))  # call 4
d = {'c': 3}
print(timeit(lambda: fun2(1, 2, *d), number=int(1e8)))  # call 5
```

```
7.7741496
8.472946400000001
9.2335016
9.755567000000003
18.6909664
```

(Note that I did additional runs randomising the order in which these functions are called and the relative results remain more or less the same)

My own reasoning: since Python would have to do a lot of analysis to know how a function is called throughout the program being run, and some calls may only execute conditionally, it can't really optimise for how the function is called. So, keyword arguments always incur a penalty and using keyword arguments with their keyword adds a penalty.

As pointed out in the comments: if you care enough about performance for this to really matter, you may want to reconsider picking Python on the standard VM as a platform. And obsessing about this type of performance issue tends to be premature regardless. The question however is not so much "how do I optimise", or "should I optimise", but "why is there actually a performance difference"?

Thanks for any comments or explanations in an answer.

Comment: See [Premature optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization) and [When to optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: I think the comment of @martineau is relevant, but my question isn't meant to inform new coders about what to do in general - I'm working on some code that will get called 100's of millions of time over the course of a single run, so I figured it would be good to know whether what I sometimes do for convenience or readability is actually incurring a cost, and why.

Comment: I completely understand the logic behind your question, it's very seductive, but the bottomline is the difference may not matter in the scheme of things, even if it's to something happening millions and millions of times — computer hardware is _very_ fast nowadays — so it all depends on context. Plus (generally speaking) if you do it when you don't need to it can take longer to produce the code, make it unreadable, as well as more difficult to maintain or enhance — all of which can take a lot of time or cost a lot. You already done a little benchmarking, so just leave it at that.

Comment: Again, I think that criticism is fair in general and in 99.99% of cases, nobody should worry about this - but I'm mainly asking because of the "why" part of my question, and was hoping to find someone that knew, willing to explain. (also note that another criticism here might be that, if you care that much about performance, you may want to reconsider choosing Python as a language - also fair, but again not the question)

Comment: Couple more things that illustrate my points: **1)** Your own timing comparisons suggest the difference is extremely minor, e.g. for 100,000,000 executions of the last two there's about a 9 second difference overall, which is approximately 0.000000089… sec for each one, i.e. next to nothing. **2)** Whatever differences exist it's merely a minor implementation detail which could change from release-to-release and likely different in the various versions of the interpreter implemented in other languages, like C, Java, etc, that exist — which precludes making any blanket statements.

Comment: I'm not sure how often I need to agree with you to satisfy your need for approval and confirmation, but I get your point - it's just not an answer to my question, which you seem to be willfully ignoring. If you know the answer, I'd appreciate you sharing it. If you don't, please stop tooting that horn. You're also welcome to feel that it's a question that doesn't need an answer - I'm of a different opinion, and nobody is forcing you to answer it or do anything with the answer.

Comment: I suppose my point is simply that it's likely no one's going to answer your question, which is fine given that it's ***so*** inconsequential. I also think the "why" part ought to be fairly obvious _especially_ to you given your experience with other languages.

Comment: I don't think something like that is ever obvious, unless you look at the code behind it - I did make a few (what I considered to be) reasonable guesses, and if you know those guesses are right, that would indeed answer my question. I was hoping for some insight from someone who had already done the work and knew the actual answer in the case of Python. If no answer is forthcoming, I may end up looking into it myself, and posting the answer

Comment: It should be evident it's going to take more clock-cycles to process something that can be referenced indirectly through a dictionary (i.e. keyword arguments) than one that can simply be accessed via a regular local-variable name look-up. I suppose you could look at the source of one of the interpreter's implementations and determine the various code-paths involved if you're really motivated…but why bother? The more important consideration would be which technique results in the best code given that the performance difference is so negligible — however you say you already know that answer.

Comment: I also had a similar question: can we speed up by using position-only arguments in place of normal ones, when they're called without keywords. So, I did similar experiments with calls 1 and 2, but with def fun2(a, b, c, /) which is rather simpler than def fun2(a, /, b, c=3) and also suits on my purpose. The result is like 10.6 sec for call 1 and 10.9 sec for call 2, quite opposite to the claim that the position-only arguments are faster. Maybe I missed something, but it seems that we don't need to put ,/ at the end of the function arguments just for speed up.